# How to add a functional field in a edit form after adding a new column in rails scaffold?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, database-migration

I needed to add a column to my scaffold model so I did a a migration running

```
class AddImgLinkToMovies < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :movies, :poster_url, :string
  end
end
```

Then I realized that there was no field to do an input in the edit form for the view, so I tried to add it in the _form.html.erb file:

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :poster_url %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :poster_url %>
  </div>
```

but then, when I try to submit in the edit view, this field doesn't update. Is there a way to insert a field of the in the edit view of this new column to update this register?

Comment: I think you forgot to add `poster_url` in your permit params.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add **:poster_url** to *movies_controller.rb* file in "movie_params" function like :

```
private
def movie_params
  params.require(:movie).permit(:param1, :param2, :poster_url)
end
```